# Android Room return type for result of JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: android, android-room

I have a following `query`, which returns list of chats and its last messages sorted by last message time:

```
SELECT c.*, m.*
FROM (SELECT local_id, local_chat_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
      FROM message
      WHERE status != 2
      GROUP BY local_chat_id) m1
INNER JOIN message m 
ON m.local_id == m1.local_id AND m.created_at == m1.max_created_at
INNER JOIN chat c
ON m1.local_chat_id == c.local_id
ORDER BY m1.max_created_at DESC
```

and corresponding method in `ChatDao`:

```
@Transaction
@Query(query)
fun getAllChats(): Flow<List<ChatWithMessage>>
```

I tested this query in database inspector and it works fine.
However, I don't know how to return the result of the query. I don't want to deal with `@Embedded` for both `Chat` and `Message` entities in `ChatWithMessage` class because they have same field `local_id`, so I would have to use `prefix` and aliases for every field of the resulting table, which is awful, because `Chat` and `Message` have about 14 fields in total.
`@Relation` inside `ChatWithMessage` class doesn't work, because it returns a list of all messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creasting that class `ChatWithMessage` "manually" (not extending or doing anything to reuse from the original data classes) containing all the fields that your query returns. You'd also need to create different labels (with a SQL command like `c.local_id AS chat_id`) for the fields with the same name in both `Chat` and `Message` entities. Your query is customized, it needs a customized result class as well.

Comment: Thank you for you response. It's better than reusing `Message` and `Chat` entities, but I still need to write many aliases in my query. Can I just return all chats with all messages using `@Relation` and transform them as I need using list transformation operations? What are the disadvantages of such approach?